# await InsertAsync error in Azure Mobile Service TableController

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services

My code was working fine but right now I get an error on all my `TableControllers` when awaiting the `InsertAsync` function. This is the code:

```
 // POST tables/Account
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAccount(Account item)
    {
        Account current = await InsertAsync(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }
```

The error says: 
`Cannot await System.Threading.Tasks.Task<sampleAppService.DataObjects.Account> expression`.

I have no idea what's causing this. Any help?

**EDIT**

The signature of the InsertAsync function

```
protected virtual Task<TData> InsertAsync (TData item);
```

Comment: Please post the  (signature of the ) `InsertAsync` method

Comment: @naffie Make sure you use the right Framework in your Project-Properties >=4.5. Further I read then someone got similiar problems because of Microsoft.Bcl. Check your dependencies and remove Microsoft.Bcl if possible.

Comment: @Peter Bons, I've added an edit that shows it's signature. Sebi, I have the Framework at 4.5 but it still fails. It has been working with the Microsoft.Bcl so I'm not sure why it would be the cause. I'll try removing it just to see if anything changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Sebi's suggestion above, all I had to do was change the .Net Framework target from  `4.5 to 4.5.1` in my case. 
That resolved the errors for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your InsertAsync() is performing some async operation which is getting awaited inside, your InsertAsync() method signature must be modified to include the async word:

```
protected virtual async Task<TData> InsertAsync (TData item)
{
    await dbContext.InsertAsync(item);
}
```